# jquery setRequestHeader JavaScript runtime error: NetworkError

Tags: jquery, authentication

I have the following code:

```
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/json");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic blablabla");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Host", "my.domain.net");
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            writeRepoInfo(data);
          }
        };
        xmlhttp.send()
```

or the following code:

```
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: requestUrl,
      crossDomain: true,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic blablabla");
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Host", "my.domain.net");
        },
      success: function (data) {
        writeRepoInfo(data);
      },
      error: function (error) {
        console.log('Failed ' + error.status + ' ' + error.statusText);
      }
    });
```

When I run I get a network error:

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: NetworkError

I used Fiddler to capture the call and I notice that the security header is not being added.  So, I am guessing that the NetworkError is really an Access Denied error.

At the same time, I know that my basic auth value is correct, because I can use Fiddler to call my url with the authorization info and it works great every time.

So, my rest service works great in Fiddler, just not is my test web app.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try it in something other than IE, looks like a same-origin-policy problem?

Comment: Yes, Chrome and Edge.

Comment: Evidently the answer is that web client calling a web service is totally different from a smart client calling a web service.  For my smart client, I did not have to have CORS turned on.  For my web client, it is required that I have CORS turned on in my web service.  This article explained it for me: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: Summary: 1) Turn on CORS in my web service.  2) Client code was:
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: url,
          beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/json");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64);
          },
          success: function (data) {
            writeRepoInfo(data);
          },
          error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#results').text(jqXHR.responseText || textStatus);
          }
        });
      }